# Consider using the "jsdom" test environment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

I have this simple test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

import Button from '.'

describe('Button', () => {
  it('renders button without crashing', () => {
    const label = 'test'

    render(<Button label={label} />)
  })
})
```

And I have a `jest.config.json` with this content

```
{
  "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
    "<rootDir>/lib/settings/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

And on my `setupTests.ts` I have

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
```

When I run `npm run test` (which just run `jest`), I got the following error:

[image]

> The error below may be caused by using the wrong test environment, see
> https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string.
>
> Consider using the "jsdom" test environment.

What I am doing wrong? This used to work before an upgrade.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

In your `package.json`, or `jest.config.js`/`jest.config.ts` file, change the value of the `testEnvironment` property to `jsdom`.

### `package.json`

```json
"jest":{
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}
```

### `jest.config.[js|ts]`

```json
module.exports = {
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom"
}
```

### Important note for jest >28

If you are using jest 28, you will need to install `jest-environment-jsdom` separately by either:

npm: `npm i jest-environment-jsdom --save-dev`

yarn: `yarn add -D jest-environment-jsdom`

### Why?

By default, jest uses the `node` testEnvironment. This essentially makes any tests meant for a browser environment invalid.

`jsdom` is an implementation of a browser environment, which supports these types of UI tests.

For Jest version 28 and greater, `jest-environment-jsdom` was removed from the default `jest` installation to reduce package size.

### Additional reading

[jest testEnvironment documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string)

[Jest 28 breaking changes](https://jestjs.io/blog/2022/04/25/jest-28#breaking-changes)

Comment: Your answer helped me. Thank you. However, what you provide as `jest.config.[js|ts]` is json format. To use that snippet, you have to change the file name to `jest.config.json`.

Comment: @Betty made the js/ts version more explicit

Comment: Is `@testing-library/jest-dom` also required for jest tests in the browser? Or does that package just add extra assertions that `jest-environment-jsdom` doesn't have natively?

Comment: @MichaelLynch I believe that is an optional package if you are using the testing-library suite, so it is not required to write basic jest tests. Your assessment on it adding additional assertions is correct.

Answer (score 26):

This can be solved on a per-test-file basis by adding a `@jest-environment` docblock to the beginning of your file. For example:

```js
/** @jest-environment jsdom */
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

import Button from '.'

describe('Button', () => {
  it('renders button without crashing', () => {
    const label = 'test'

    render(<Button label={label} />)
  })
})
```

If your project has a mix of UI and non-UI files, this is often preferable to [changing the entire project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69228464/25507) by setting `"testEnvironment": "jsdom"` within your package.json or Jest config. By skipping initializing the JSDom environment for non-UI tests, Jest can run your tests faster. In fact, that's why Jest [changed the default test environment in Jest 27](https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27#flipping-defaults).

Comment: /** @jest-environment jsdom */ worked when place on top of file but didn't work when placed above a test method. Do you know why?

Comment: @redochka - It can only be changed on a per-file basis, not per-method. See https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

Comment: thanks you! great explanation, I need jsdom for angular component tests, but firebase firestore rules tests need the node environment to run properly.  This lets me set the right environment for each file.

Answer (score 2):

by default the value for testEnvironment is **node** which runs all test cases in node.js envioronment, but js-dom provides browser like enviornment. instead of adding jsdom value, you can even add file specific value like below which will work.

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
// the above comment helps
test('use jsdom in this test file', () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  expect(element).not.toBeNull();
});
```

We can even add test file specific environments, please refer this link.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
module.exports = {
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).